# Text Animation Flickering Problem in CSS and React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

I managed to achieve this animation through CSS animations and React. but go stuck in flickering problem. I don't know why this is happening maybe 'cause I used `setInterval` or there is some problem with my css animations keyframes. help me to solve this problem. the flicker only occurs after some time. and after refreshing the page the animation works perfectly fine without flicker problem.

this is how the animation looks after refreshing the page and this is what I want too. (ignore the screen recorder watermark).

[animation I want](https://i.imgur.com/vEmmpW8.mp4)

but after sometime the animation starts flickering like this.

[Flickering problem](https://i.imgur.com/o361fIZ.mp4)

here are the code snippets I wrote
jsx snippet

```html
<div className="relative w-[280px] md:w-[350px] lg:w-[500px]">
  <span>{"[ "}</span>

  <p className="text_animate ml-2">
    {dev ? "for" : "by"} Developers
  </p>

  <span className="absolute right-0 ">{" ]"}</span>
</div>
```

css snippet

```css
.text_animate {
  color: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  text-align: start;
  animation: text-up 6s linear infinite;
  cursor: none;
}
    
@keyframes text-up {
  0% {
    top:45px;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  20% {
    top:0;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  35% {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  50% {
    top: -45px;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  52% {
    top: 45px;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  70% {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  85% {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    top: -45px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

useState changing text

```js
const [dev, setDev] = useState(true);

setInterval(() => {
  setDev(!dev);
}, 3000);
```

If there is any better way to achieve this I would really love to learn so let me know that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should put `setInterval` to `useEffect`, and remember to clear timer. Like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    setDev(!dev);
  }, 3000);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, []);
```

And there is a solution only using css to implement this, I will write a demo later.

**EDIT:**

Explain the above code:

`useEffect` with `[]` as second param will make sure run `setInterval` once when mount the component.

The `clearInterval` in return function will make sure engine GC the variables in setInterval callback functions when unmount the component, or the setInterval will still work even though you needn't it.

CSS only solution:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.scroll-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: calc(var(--line-h) * 1px);
  line-height: calc(var(--line-h) * 1px);
  font-size: 18px;
}

.scroll-container ul {
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: calc(var(--speed) * var(--lines));
  animation-timing-function: steps(var(--lines));
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.scroll-container ul li {
  animation-name: li-move;
  animation-duration: var(--speed);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, calc(var(--lines) * var(--line-h) * -1px));
  }
}

@keyframes li-move {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, calc(var(--line-h) * -1px));
  }
}
```

```html
<div
  class="scroll-container"
  style="--lines: 2; --line-h: 26; --speed: 3s"
>
  <ul>
      <li>For Developers</li>
      <li>By Developers</li>
      <!-- repeat first in tail for infinity -->
      <li>For Developers</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I leaned this from [Chokcoco on CodePen](https://codepen.io/Chokcoco) but forget which post.

Comment: thanks alot, this solved the issue. can you please explain why it's necessary to clear the timer the need of using `useEffect` and I'm also looking forward to CSS only method you wrote about.

Comment: You can use the hook called useLayoutEffect Here is the link to it so that you know when and how to use it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wU57kvYOxT4

Comment: @UNRIVALLEDKING Sorry for my later reply. Updated explanations for `useEffect` and add css only solution. Let me see if you have other problems.

Comment: @MeetBhalodiya `useLayoutEffect` is useful, but I remember it will block the renderer if there is a calculation intensive operation(correct me if wrong). So I like use `useEffect`.

Comment: @LiHS thanks alot for your explanation. and I liked that css only solution too. I'm new to css animations so I don't much about that. can you explain `50%,
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, calc(var(--line-h) * -1px));
  }`  how 50%,100% written consecutively works? and which one you prefer to use css only or using react states

Comment: @UNRIVALLEDKING You may have noticed that `--speed` is the time each line stay(include move). So, the `--speed: 2s` and `50%, 100% {...}` means the line will stay `2s * (100% - 50%) = 1s` (exclude move). If you change it to `70%, 100% {...}`,you will get `2s * (100% - 70%) = 0.6s` stay time. In a word, this control the line stay duration and move duration.

Comment: @UNRIVALLEDKING I prefer use css only to do this job, if I don't need to think about compatibility with old browsers. Because this animation is not too complex and it's the job css should do. ;)

Comment: @LiHS thanks alot, can you recommend to some place or doc to learn more about css animations

Comment: @UNRIVALLEDKING I'm sorry I can't. Because except for [CSS Animations Guides on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations) and [pens 
 tagged css-animation on CodePen](https://codepen.io/tag/css-animation), the other documents about css I read were written in Chinese, such as [iCSS - GitHub](https://github.com/chokcoco/iCSS) and [css blog - zhangxinxu](https://www.zhangxinxu.com/wordpress/category/css/). They may be a bit difficult to read, if you don't speak Chinese.

Comment: @LiHS no worries, thanks for your help, I will study more css animations thorugh codepen.